# Trust anchor for certification path not found when using API

Tags: android

I’m making a news app and I’m using newsapi.org to get the news. I tried my app on the emulator and on one device and it works correctly but then I tried it on another device and I get this error: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found. Does anyone know why this might be happening?
Thanks in advance!